# cygwin awk output files containing string

Tags: awk, grep, cygwin

Okay so I wish to search my C drive for multiple .txt files containing the name "Public"

example of file names

```
 public.txt
 publicagain.txt
 etc etc
```

and then output them into a folder

Answer (score 0):

`cd C:` and use the below find command

```
find -type f -iname '*public*'
```